# Как выбрать количество элементов масива $_POST?

Tags: массивы, post

Есть два инпута:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name = "var1">
<input type="text" name = "var2">
</form>
```

Нужно получить количество введеных\переданных значений, делаю так:

```
count($_POST);
```

Но, `var_dump(count($_POST))` всегда показывает `int(2)` в независимости от количества введенных значений. В чем ошибка или такая проверка некорректна?

Comment: Ну видимо потому, что вы в пост запросе в любом случае отправляете все инпуты, просто у одного заполнено поле, а у другого нет.. Всё логично

Answer (score 2):

```
$amount = 0;
foreach($_POST as $value) {
    if (isset($value) && $value !== '') {
        $amount++;
    }
}

var_dump($amount) or die;
```